# Scrollview containing two tableviews on same screen limits scrolling vertically

Tags: ios, ipad, uitableview, uiscrollview

I have two uitableviews in a uiscrollview.  I am displaying the scrollview on one ipad screen so it shows both tableviews simultaneously (ie: tableview on left and tableview on right).

I have "communal scrolling" of the tableviews working (where you scroll one tableview and it moves the other in sync) by using this code:

```
    - (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
{
    static BOOL isObservingContentOffsetChange = NO;
    if([object isKindOfClass:[UITableView class]]
       && [keyPath isEqualToString:@"contentOffset"])
    {
        if(isObservingContentOffsetChange) return;

        isObservingContentOffsetChange = YES;

        if(theTableViewLEFT != object)
        {
            CGPoint offset = [[change valueForKey:NSKeyValueChangeNewKey] CGPointValue];
            theTableViewLEFT.contentOffset = offset;
        }
        if(theTableViewRIGHT != object)
        {
            CGPoint offset = [[change valueForKey:NSKeyValueChangeNewKey] CGPointValue];
            theTableViewRIGHT.contentOffset = offset;
        }

        isObservingContentOffsetChange = NO;
        return;
    }

    [super observeValueForKeyPath:keyPath ofObject:object change:change context:context];
}
```

So, that works fine. It is a scrollview with 2 total tableviews inserted.  The scrolling of each view works fine.   The issue?  When one table is longer (goes off the screen) than the other table and you scroll the shorter table, they both stop scrolling vertically where the shorter table ends.  ie: if the left table is longer than the right, and you scroll the right vertically, they both stop scrolling where the right table ends.  However, if you scroll the left table, then they both scroll all the way to the end of the left table, ie: The right table scrolls up and off the screen while you still see things in the longer table.  This is the way i want it to operate.

I really cannot tell people to scroll using the longer table.  How can I get both tables to scroll the entire height of the longer table?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use tableViews as subViews for ScrollView, then you must disable the scroll options. Since, tableView inherits from scrollView.

So, Instead of adding an observer, you can disable the scollEnabled property for tableviews. So the tableViews willnot scroll any more. and give the maximum content size of tableViews as the scroll View ContentSize. So, if you scroll any table, they will scroll to the maximum of TableView contentSize.

Eg :

```
UITableView *tblView1;// this is your left table View
UITableView *tblView2;// this is your right TableView

tblView1.scrollEnabled= NO;
tblView2.scrollEnabled= NO;

CGSize maxSize = CGSizeMake(MAX(tblView1.contentSize.width,  tblView2.contentSize.width), MAX(tblView1.contentSize.height, tblView2.contentSize.height));
```

now set This max Size to your scrollView's contentSize property.

```
scrollView.contentSize = maxSize;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not clear on the purpose of putting the table views into a scroll view, as they are both scroll views themselves. However, to answer your question, you just need to set the `contentInset` of your shorter table view so that its `bottom` is equal to the difference in height of the two tables.